# Why is one file sent to the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I wrote a function "import File" which have to send several files to the server. Only one file comes to the server.

Input:

```
<input
   type="files"
   id="files"
   name="files"
   multiple
   onChange={ (e) => this.importFile(e.target.files) }
/>
```

Function:

```
importFile(file: File) {
   const fd = new FormData();
   let filesArr = [];
   for (let key in file) {
       if(file[key] instanceof File) {
         filesArr.push(file[key]);
       }
   }
   for (let i = 0; i < filesArr.length; i++) {
      fd.append('file', filesArr[i]);
   }
   post('/file/attachment', fd)
       .then((res) => {
          this.props.importFile([res]);
        })
       .catch((e) => console.error(e));
}
```

Comment: `fd.append('file'` you use the same parameter name for each appended file, they need to be unique. Otherwise its going just use the last one set

Comment: fd.append('file[]', filesArr[i]); try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're server minght only be picking single file in `formData`.

Try `fd.append('file[]', filesArr[i])` instead.

When using `[]` in front of key name multiple values can be appended as written in [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example) see example 3.

Comment: Actually, you're not overwriting them, whatever server-side framework you're using is only giving you one of the entries.  The linked MDN says "As with regular form data, you can append multiple values with the same name."  You may be able to get all the entries if you use a different method in your server-side web-framework (e. g. accepting `File[]` instead of `File` or calling `getlist('files')` instead of `get('files')`)

Comment: @SeanVieira thanks for pointing it out, ill update the language of answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
fd.append(`file${i}`, filesArr[i]);
```